# Hide and show multiple pageBlocks in Salesforce?

Tags: apex

I want hide and show multiple pageblock in my vf ,

this i smy vf

```
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:commandButton value="A Section" action="{!me 1}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="B Section" action="{!me 2}"/>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!game 1}">
   <apex:outputText value="This is A section"/>
</apex:pageBlock>    

<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!game 2}">
   <apex:outputText value="This is B section"/>
</apex:pageBlock>      

</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a controller for your vf for using that controller you can hide and show multiple pageblock

```
public class sample
{
    public Boolean game1{get;set;}
    public Boolean game2{get;set;} 

    public sample()
    {
        game1= false;
        game2= false;    
    }   
    public void callA()
    {
        game1= = true;
        game2= = false;
    }   
    public void callB()
    {
        game1= = false;
        game2= = true;    
    }     
}
```